# How do I get every nth row in a table, or how do I break up a subset of a table into sets or rows of equal size?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of heterogeneous pieces of data identified by a primary key (ID) and a type identifier (TYPE_ID).  I would like to be able to perform a query that returns me a set of ranges for a given type broken into even page sizes.  For instance, if there are 10,000 records of type '1' and I specify a page size of 1000, I want 10 pairs of numbers back representing values I can use in a `BETWEEN` clause in subsequent queries to query the DB 1000 records at a time.

My initial attempt was something like this

```
select id, rownum from CONTENT_TABLE 
where type_id = ? and mod(rownum, ?) = 0
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rownum` is "evaluated" when the selected records are returned, after
evaluating the `where clause` of a select query. Therefore, you need to
select on rownum in an another query. I give r as an alias for rownum:

```
select id from (
  select 
    id, 
    rownum r
  from 
    CONTENT_TABLE 
   where type_id = ? 
)
where mod(r, ?) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found roughly the same information here:  http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at NTILE?
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#i1014248

Comment: If you're looking to subdivide a result set into equivalently-sized result sets, NTILE() is a better choice.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Use below SQL to find the every nth row in a table:

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE (ROWID,0) in (SELECT ROWID, MOD(ROWNUM, n)
FROM table_name);
Replace n with 2, 3, 4 , 5 ...
```

Comment: Hi @The_Black_Smurf there is nothing wrong with the 2010 answer. But I assume there is always scope for improvement. At first, I came up with different solution as you can see, it's not a duplicate one. Secondly, there should be freedom for the end user too  to take their decision :) However,  thanks for your feedback.